# How can we get keys of an object?

Tags: typescript

Suppose We have an interface A that has two properties:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  };
}

type Key = ???????

const test: Key[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

so how can we define and make it work to get all the nested keys in A?

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyAzmFKAOYDcu+ARsdnvsgsWRSDXcgL60cfXCJxgAngAcUAaQjjkAXmQB+NepWiEAexBlkkMsTniA2gF0lyUwHI4NgDTIb9R84Q3zgoA).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve here?

Comment: `A` defines a completely different type than you are using in `test`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Sorry if my description is not clear for you, my goal is to get all nested keys: a, b and c for Key type. Actually if we see we got another answers here down they are exactly what I am looking for. :) Thank you very much for your comments. appriecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a conditional type that applies the [`keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) to all objects and recursively in those objects' properties.  For example:

```
type NestedKeyof<T> = T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: K | NestedKeyof<T[K]> }[keyof T]
  : never
```

This works for your example code:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  };
}

type Key = NestedKeyof<A>;
// type Key = "a" | "b" | "c"

const test: Key[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

There are always caveats, so you should test this against your real use cases.  For instance, if you write `NestedKey<Tree>` with `interface Tree { prop: Tree }`, you'll get a circularity warning (which makes sense).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyAzmFKAOYDcu+ARsdnvsgsWRSDXcgL60cfXLjABPAA4oAchDIQAJgGkIYgPYwAPABUAfMgC8ybcggAPSCAUlka+gCsICMMgD8vDMgDaS5KGQA1qoaxgC6xL4APsiy8srBWto+ofp8XkHqMGG8xCAQAG7QIjjiUsgqYoYxcpDxmZqouoIA9M3IpSgVVQBEcN3I0d30-YMI3cUIaiBk7TURql6hVV4A5HArADTIK-Sb2wgroYK4QA)

Comment: Although this is a great answer and I upvoted, I also share the skepticism of the commenters on the question that this has any sort of desirable practical application. Is there ever a time you would actually *need* this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an util type that get's all the keys of the object recursively, something like:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
  };
}


// create a type that gets keys recursively
type RecursiveKeyOf1<TObj extends object> = {
  [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: TObj[TKey] extends object
    ? `${TKey}` | `${RecursiveKeyOf<TObj[TKey]>}`
    : `${TKey}`;
}[keyof TObj & (string | number)];

// create a type for the object's keys
type ObjectKeys = RecursiveKeyOf1<A> // "a" | "b" | "c"

const keys: ObjectKeys[] = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're using template literal types here?